# How to access highstock zoom buttons via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there a way to access `highstock` zoom buttons via jquery as follows

```
$('.highcharts-range-selector-buttons').attr('user', 'free');
```

I want to add a new attribute to the range selector buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to wait until the range selector is rendered. E.g. it is rendered before load event, so you can grab the element there.

```
chart: {
  type: 'arearange',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const el = $('.highcharts-range-selector-buttons').attr('user', 'free')
      console.log(el.attr('user'))
    }
  }
},
```

The class you have is for the group which includes buttons. Range selector buttons have classes `highcharts-button [highcharts-button-pressed / highcharts-button-normal]`

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v2gv7um1/